# gulp ruby sass and concat is putting my sourcemap inside css

Tags: sass, gulp, source-maps, event-stream, gulp-sass

I'm using `event-stream` so that I can compile SASS and merge it with CSS in one task. It's working great my only problem is the `sourcemap` is getting merged inside the CSS.

**gulp code**

```
gulp.task('css', function(){

    var sassGlob = "assets/css/**/*.scss";
    var cssGlob = "assets/css/**/*.css";;
    var dest = "./dist/css/min/'";

    // compile sass
    var sassFiles = gulp.src(sassGlob)
    .pipe(plugins.rubySass({
        style: 'expanded', precision: 2
    }));

    // concatenate css + compiled sass
    return es.concat(gulp.src(cssGlob), sassFiles)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});
```

source: **main.SCSS**

```
header {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

source: **main2.css**

```
body {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

output: **style.min.css**

```
body {
    padding: 2px;
}

header {
  padding: 2px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */

{
"version": 3,
"mappings": "AAAA,IAAK;EACD,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG",
"sources": ["../main.scss"],
"names": [],
"file": "main.css"
}
```

**Things I've tried**

1) **tried:** setting sourcemap of rubySass to false **result:** no difference

```
.pipe(plugins.rubySass({
    style: 'expanded', sourcemap: 'none', precision: 2
}));
```

2. **tried:** `gulp-concat-sourcemap`, this creates my external sourcemap file but I still also have it inside my `style.min.css`

   return es.concatSourceMap(gulp.src(cssGlob), sassFiles)
           .pipe(plugins.concat('style.min.css'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));

When I inspected the output of the resulting sourcemap I noticed this

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "style.min.css",
  "sources": [
    "assets/css/other.css",
    "main2.css",
    "main2.css.map"
  ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": "AAAA;AACA;AACA;;ACFA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;;ACLA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA"
}
```

Based on that it seems it's concatenating the .map file to the CSS which is the behavior we see. 
So I tried to filter it out.

3) **tried:** using `gulp-filter` to filter out the map file from being concatenated in the css **result:** no difference

```
return es.merge(cssFiles, sassFiles)
        .pipe($.filter("!*.map))
```

"))

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue not long ago. It's related to how the parameters are passed to the *sass gem* using **dargs**, you can found more info about it [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dargs/pull/3#issuecomment-52884240).

Since the [#114](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/pull/114), this is however supposed to work.

One little hacky solution was given by *[@milesj](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/113#issuecomment-53778451)* and fix the problem for now:

```
.pipe(plugins.rubySass({
  style: 'expanded', 'sourcemap=none': true, precision: 2
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! This at least gives one way of using this without the sourcemap. But do you know how I could keep generating this source map without it getting merged in the same file with my CSS?

Comment: Check the [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sourcemap-option) for all available options.